# Rails - Capitalize Article Tags and Titles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Am trying to find a way of capitalizing the 1st letter of all Titles and Tags when a user submits an article. I can use the capitalize method, but where do I add it to the controller code blocks for it to work?

Thx

controllers/articles_controller:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
 end
end
```

controllers/tags_controller:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @articles = @tag.articles
  end
end
```

models/article:

```
def tag_names
  @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
end

private

def assign_tags
  if @tag_names
    self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\,/).map do |name|
    Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
 ...
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of plugin to do the tags?

Comment: @Douglas - no plugins are being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this to force them to be capitalized before saving.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title=(title)
    write_attribute(:title, title.titleize)
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\,/).map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name.capitalize)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: am I right in thinking you would add the function in the model as opposed to the controllers using your example? Could you help me with this code block (have posted above)?

Comment: how would you limit the Tags so that only the 20 most popular were on display at any one time? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Where do you plan to capitalize it? before saving in the database? or when you're showing it to the user?

There are two ways to this:

Use rail's [titleize function](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) or [capitalize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-capitalize)

or do it using CSS with:

```
 <p class="tag">im a tag</p>

 #CSS
 .tag {
   text-transform:capitalize;
 }
```

Comment: I want to save it before it goes into the db

Comment: what's the difference? anyway in your controller intercept the parameter you want to capitalize then just call .capitalize or .titleize

Comment: I like the css approach but using .capitalize / .titleize would be a new way of doing this for me, so am keen to try it out. Where do I put them in the controller code blocks tho?

Comment: IMHO, saving it as capitalized will give you more trouble than showing it as capitalized. First, you have to intercept the params, use titleize/capitalize, merge it back to params and create/save your object. if you just saved it as lowercase or whichever, you could easily show it using CSS OR in your view, you could just do <%= @tag.titleize %>

Comment: I'll use that answer. Thx! I was wondering if to call capitalize for so many strings so many times is not a bit much effort for the server when your user's browser can do it instead of the server. Is the CSS method taking a lot of resources on the client side?

Comment: I don't think the CSS way will take a lot of resources. It would take like a million words or something for it to even affect the browser slightly. And if that happens, you have a different problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .capitalize

e.g. "title".capitalize will make "Title"

Answer (score 0):

As Francis said, use .capitalize in your controller

I use this

```
@article= Article.new(params[:article])
@article.name = @article.title.capitalize 
@article.save
```

Comment: thanks. This approach throws up an error when I add it. Have added my controller code blocks above to see if anyone can still help!